# Redirecting the users on the network to a default page. (Wireless Router)

Tags: wireless-router, redirection, captive-portal

I have a cable modem connected to wireless router (Asus RT-N10 D1) that lets me and my neighbor connect to the Internet. We agreed to share the cost of Internet together since the Internet is expensive in our country.

My profession requires every-day Internet connection, therefore I have to pay the internet fee always on time. I cannot let the ISP to turn off my Internet and cause an income loss. And, I am the type of a person who hesitate to talk about money with people. Let's say too kind to request money from someone.

In short, when my neighbor do not pay me the half of the Internet cost, I want to redirect him to a specific page that we face when we do not pay for the Internet. I do not know how to accomplish this task. I have made few search on Google and found out that you can do it with DD-WRT. I am not sure whether my router is supported. I do not want to risk bricking the router (http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=169934). Is there any other certain way to do this so called 'Captive portal' thing using Asus RT-N10 D1 (https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN10Plus_D1/specifications/)?

Thank You

EDIT: There is not (+) sign in my router's model

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question now that you know your hardware is compatible with DD-WRT

Answer (score 0):

Redirection may be very hard to do. Anyway you can just set up the router to accept only specific MAC addresses to connect to it to accomplish what you need.